# Error generating a signed APK in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to generate a APK from the menu Build -> Generate Signed APK in android studio.But I couldn't generate the APK file.The following errors are occuring.

[image]

Comment: did you tried clean and build and generate apk again?

Comment: yes but, it does not work.

Comment: post your gradle file code for more clarification

Comment: Which version of AS you have used?

Comment: I'm using Android Studio version 3.3.1